# Is there any way to make an HTML element immutable?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Suppose I want to make the H1 tag of this question in this page immutable,

is there any way to do this so that if anyone runs the following code, the background won't change to red?

```
document.querySelector("h1").style.backgroundColor="red"
```

or make it impossible for it to be removed using this code?

```
document.querySelector("h1").remove()
```

I tried using Object.freeze, but it did not work.

Comment: Don't think so, but you can make it more *difficult* for changes to be made

Comment: @CertainPerformance how's that? It's trivial for someone to use the DOM inspector to find the selector to the element and update it - presuming it's the goal of the OP to prevent this, of course,

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I was thinking... create a dummy `style` property or `remove` method on the element itself so that calls don't fall through to `HTMLElement.prototype`. Easy to bypass, but it'd prevent the exact lines in the question from resulting in changes

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. Why do you want to do that, what is the goal?

Comment: I have an app that adds HTML on top of the existing website, I came up with several methods to place the HTML on the correct place and not have it removed, including event listeners, mutation observers, computing the style, etc… The problem is that sometimes that’s not enough and I thought there was already a built in solution, like object.freeze for javascript objects. 

The easiest solution would be adding a mutation observer to the entire window, but that would not be good for performance.